# Pandas: Conditional left-join using date-intervals

Tags: python, pandas, join, conditional-operator

I have two dataframes, `df1` and `df_weight`:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date': [pd.to_datetime("2023-01-01"),
                             pd.to_datetime("2023-01-01"),
                             pd.to_datetime("2024-01-01"),
                             pd.to_datetime("2025-01-01"),
                             pd.to_datetime("2026-01-01"),

                             pd.to_datetime("2030-01-01"),
                             pd.to_datetime("2031-01-01"),
                             pd.to_datetime("2032-01-01"),
                             pd.to_datetime("2033-01-01"),
                             pd.to_datetime("2034-01-01"),

                             pd.to_datetime("2080-01-01"),
                             pd.to_datetime("2081-01-01")],
                    'val':   [*range(12)]})

df_weight = pd.DataFrame({'date': [pd.to_datetime("2023-01-01"),
                                    pd.to_datetime("2030-01-01"),
                                    pd.to_datetime("2035-01-01")],
                          'weight': [10,20,30]})
```

I want to left-join `df_weight` on to `df1` to add the `weight`-column to `df1` using the common `date`-column. However, I want the following logic:

Add the value of `df_weight.weight` to `df1` for which `df1.date` is in a given `df_weight.date` interval, i.e., the newly-added `weight`-column should look like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date': [pd.to_datetime("2023-01-01"),
                             pd.to_datetime("2023-01-01"),
                             pd.to_datetime("2024-01-01"),
                             pd.to_datetime("2025-01-01"),
                             pd.to_datetime("2026-01-01"),

                             pd.to_datetime("2030-01-01"),
                             pd.to_datetime("2031-01-01"),
                             pd.to_datetime("2032-01-01"),
                             pd.to_datetime("2033-01-01"),
                             pd.to_datetime("2034-01-01"),

                             pd.to_datetime("2080-01-01"),
                             pd.to_datetime("2081-01-01")],
                    'val': [*range(12)],
                    'weight': [10,10,10,10,10,
                               20,20,20,20,20,
                               30,30]})
```

Is this possible with pandas?

Comment: use merge_asof `pd.merge_asof(df1, df_weight)` https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html